# rebol esmtp failure?

Tags: rebol

I wanted to try esmtp with smtp.hotpop.com

```
esend myfriend@yahoo.com "Test"
```

using http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=esmtp.r and
http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=esend.r

but it fails.

What's wrong ?

Here is all the information you should need to help you set up your mail client:

```
* Incoming/POP Server: pop.hotpop.com, port 110
* Alternate POP Server: pop.hotpop.com, port 1100
* Username: reboltutorial@HotPOP.com
* Outgoing/SMTP Server: smtp.hotpop.com, port 25*
* Email Address: reboltutorial@HotPOP.com
* Reply-To Address: reboltutorial@HotPOP.com (or any other email address you have)
* Leave Messages on server: false (some clients will instead have a "Delete messages from server" option, which should be set to true).
* Maximum Message Size: 500 KB (512000 bytes)
* Mailbox Size: 10 MB
* Mailbox Usage: 0.0% (0.0 KB)
```

*HotPOP's outgoing (SMTP) mail server requires authentication. The username and password are the same as the POP Server and website. Do not select "secure" password authentication.

Comment: "It fails" is extremely vague. I'd suggest adding the exact error and maybe even a trace.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I couldn't get much of a response from this site .. and there are 100+ questions to answer to signup for their free service.

But esmtp is now built into the latest rebol binaries.  no need to use one from the library.

so ...try the following

set-net [ reboltutorial@hotpop.com smtp.hotpop.com ]
trace/net on
send reboltutorial@hotpop.com "testing"

and see what error message comes up.
the protocol should ask you for your userid and password so that you can authenticate.