# Rebol 2 esmtp cannot decode AUTH parameter

Tags: authentication, rebol

Set set-net with appropriate values, but get this message when trying to send an email using esmtp.r from rebol.org. Any ideas what this means?

Comment: This post suggests using the built-in esmtp in Rebol2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320021/rebol-esmtp-failure

Answer (score 3):

OK. I tried and was successful sending a message using Rebol2's built-in 'send function. Here is a transcript of my session:

```
>> help set-net
USAGE:
    SET-NET settings

DESCRIPTION:
     Network setup.  All values after default are optional.  Words OK for server names.
     SET-NET is a function value.

ARGUMENTS:
     settings -- [email-addr default-server pop-server proxy-server proxy-port-id proxy-type esmtp-user
esmtp-pass] (Type: block)
>> set-net [blechnow@server.net "mail.sonic.net" "mail.sonic.net" none none none "blechnow" "<removed my password>"]
>> help esend
Found these words:
   resend          function! Relay a message

>> help send
USAGE:
    SEND address message /only /header header-obj /attach files /subject subj /show

DESCRIPTION:
     Send a message to an address (or block of addresses)
     SEND is a function value.

ARGUMENTS:
     address -- An address or block of addresses (Type: email block)
     message -- Text of message. First line is subject. (Type: any)

REFINEMENTS:
     /only -- Send only one message to multiple addresses
     /header -- Supply your own custom header
         header-obj -- The header to use (Type: object)
     /attach -- Attach file, files, or [.. [filename data]]
         files -- The files to attach to the message (Type: file block)
     /subject -- Set the subject of the message
         subj -- The subject line (Type: any)
     /show -- Show all recipients in the TO field
>> trace/net on ;This turns on tracing so you can see what is going on at the network level
>> send bo@server.com {Test}
Net-log: ["Opening" "tcp" "for" "esmtp"]
connecting to: mail.sonic.net
Net-log: [none "220"]
Net-log: "220 mail.sonic.net ESMTP [c]"
Net-log: [["EHLO" system/network/host] "250"]
Net-log: {250-c.mail.sonic.net Hello exchange.domain.local [50.255.255.211] (may be forged), pleased to meet you}
Net-log: "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
Net-log: "250-PIPELINING"
Net-log: "250-8BITMIME"
Net-log: "250-SIZE 35882577"
Net-log: "250-DSN"
Net-log: "250-ETRN"
Net-log: "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN"
Net-log: "250-STARTTLS"
Net-log: "250-DELIVERBY"
Net-log: "250 HELP"
Net-log: ["Supported auth methods:" [plain login]]
Net-log: ["WARNING! Using AUTH LOGIN."]
Net-log: [
    "AUTH LOGIN" "334"
]
Net-log: "334 VX******c="
Net-log: ["Ym******U6" "334"]
Net-log: "334 UG******=="
Net-log: ["Mz******Q6" "235"]
Net-log: "235 2.0.0 OK Authenticated"
Net-log: ["MAIL FROM: <blechnow@server.net>" "250"]
Net-log: "250 2.1.0 <blechnow@server.net>... Sender ok"
Net-log: ["RCPT TO: <bo@server.com>" "250"]
Net-log: "250 2.1.5 <bo@server.com>... Recipient ok"
Net-log: ["DATA" "354"]
Net-log: {354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself}
Net-log: [none "250"]
Net-log: {250 2.0.0 u9******49 Message accepted for delivery}
Net-log: ["QUIT" "221"]
Net-log: "221 2.0.0 c.mail.sonic.net closing connection"
```